# In Xcode, is there a single key command that will hide the navigator, debug area and inspector all at once?

Tags: xcode

When I'm writing code in Xcode (as opposed to debugging or browsing the source tree), I like to use the whole window for editing. Is there a single command that will hide the navigator, inspector and debug area, so the entire window is just my source file?

I know there are shortcuts to do each of these individually, but that's not quite as convenient.

Comment: Why not write a script that you can trigger with a single keyboard shortcut?

Comment: @matt What sort of script?

Comment: Depends how snazzy you want to get. The way I would do it is thru AppleScript and SystemEvents, because that lets you choose the corresponding menu items. I would store that with FastScripts to give it a keyboard shortcut. Quick and dirty.